# AWS Elastic Load Balancer And 408 Request Timeout

Tags: timeout, amazon-elb, request

We have a scenario where we are trying to access Openfire admin console behind AWS ELB using `https`.  The `http` url works fine , but the `https` does not work, and we see a `408 request timeout` error while debugging in the browser. We then went ahead and enabled the ELB Access logs. But on inspecting log files we do not find any information related to our request. For example we are not seeing information related to our `GET` request and neither 408 error in the log. So we are not sure how we can investigate this further.

Thanks

Comment: After how much time does this 408 response occur?  What HTTP client are you using?

Comment: Yes the 408 error occurs exactly after 1 minute.

Comment: We are using Mozilla, to debug this issue

Comment: We had missed the https port entry in the security group. But I still wonder, why in this case load balancer did not log anything in the Access logs. Anyway this is solved now.

Comment: @user1525825 do you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Configure HTTPS for Elastic Beanstalk environment -> https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-https-configuration/